# BitBucket - Git - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

First of all, I would like you to know that I have read thoroughly 20+ posts on the topic. However, it is still not working after 2 days, so... I finally give up and acknowledge that I CANNOT set up this ssh connection...

Ok, painful enough. Now here is what I did (at least 3 times) :

1. I generate a set of ssh keys with the command :

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa
   ```
2. Here are the permissions for both the `.ssh` folder and the `rsa keys` :

   ```
   $ ls -al | grep .ssh
   drwx------  2 local local     4096 mars  28 11:17 .ssh

   $ ls -al .ssh/
   -rw-r--r--  1 local local  802 mars  11 17:11 authorized_keys
   -rw-r--r--  1 local local   61 mars  28 11:17 config
   -rw-------  1 local local 1675 mars  28 11:14 id_rsa
   -rw-------  1 local local  396 mars  28 11:14 id_rsa.pub
   -rw-------  1 local local 1326 mars  25 17:38 known_hosts
   ```
3. I copied the content of `id_rsa_.pub` to my BitBucket account. I am sure this is done flawlessly, I triple checked.
4. I edited `.ssh/config` so it looks like this :

   ```
   $ cat .ssh/config 
   Host bitbucket.org
   IdentityFile /home/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   ```
5. And here is the output of `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` :

   ```
   $ ssh -v git@bitbucket.org                                                                                                                                                                         
   OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
   debug1: Reading configuration data /home/local/.ssh/config
   debug1: /home/local/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bitbucket.org
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
   debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [131.103.20.168] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /home/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
   debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
   debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
   debug1: identity file /home/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u2
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
   debug1: Server host key: RSA 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40
   debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
   debug1: Found key in /home/local/.ssh/known_hosts:3
   debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
   debug1: Remote: Forced command: conq username:happy-dev
   debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
   debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
   debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
   debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
   debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
   debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
   debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
   Enter passphrase for key '/home/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pub': 
   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
   Permission denied (publickey).
   ```

If you have any idea why I still get the `Permission denied (publickey)` message, please do share it with me. I am in great despair :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IdentityFile /home/local/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

You're using the public key file here. You should use the private key file instead. It's probably called `id_rsa`:

```
IdentityFile /home/local/.ssh/id_rsa
```